# Wordpress SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: wordpress

i am loading one iframe in wordpress for login when user do login they got error like SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.xxxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. and my site has also same Protocol.
can anyone please tell me what is problem with this...

Comment: looks like cross domain issue

Comment: @atinder cant we access cross domain site?